# Shape down only a specific part of a bash ouput command

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts

I have a simple program that I call an ipsweep. All that it is supposed to do is to ping an IP address, and show the IPs under use.

This is what I did the first time:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in {1...254}; do
ping -c 1 $1.$ip
done
```

It worked, but it's showing information that I don't need. All I need is the IP addresses under use. It showed all this with each IP:

[image]

So I tried adding some filters like `| grep "ping" | cut -d " " -f 2`

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in {1...254}; do
ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "ping" | cut -d " " -f 2 &
done
```

Now the console shows only the IPs, but it shows ALL the IPs, no matter if it are in user or not (I only need the ones under use, I repeat). I've been trying to solve this for 5 hours, but I'm still unable to it. I know that with an if this could be solved, but I don't know how to write it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe fping is better suited... ```fping -ag 192.168.1.0/24``` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ping exit code to determine whether host is alive:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for ip in {1..254}; do
  ping -q -c 1 $1.$ip >2 2>&- && printf %s.%s\\n $1 $ip
done
```

Comment: What you wrote works! Thank you so much. Anyway, something is not working... Each time I write the commands "./ipsweep.sh {ip}" It shows me different results, it cant be right...

https://i.gyazo.com/99fbc220270be13b149e155be972bae3.png

Comment: has not been able to reproduce the problem, only thing I can think of  if you have missed a char somewhere

Answer (score 0):

First, checking connectivity with a single packet is unwise, but:

```
# IP address 192.168.100.1 exists, 192.168.100.122 does not.
walt@bat:~(0)$ ping -c 1 192.168.100.1
PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.76 ms

--- 192.168.100.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.763/2.763/2.763/0.000 ms
walt@bat:~(0)$ ping -c 1 192.168.100.122
PING 192.168.100.122 (192.168.100.122) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.100.122 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Both success and failure examples contain the "`--- 192.168.100.122 ping statistics ---`" line you're detecting with `grep ping`.

You could `grep ", 0% packet loss"` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't say thank you in commenrts, rather click the Accepted check mark if this answer solved your problem.